# React - class declared but never used, but it is used

Tags: reactjs

Here, my IDE is complaining that searchBar is declared but never used. However, I use it in my template class. Also, when I run the react-app, I can't see the text from the searchBar class. What's going on here?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Header from './header'
import Footer from './footer'

class searchBar extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <p>search bar here</p>
     </div>
   )
 }
}


class Layout extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <Header />
       <searchBar />
       <Footer />
     </div >
   )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Layout />,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: IIRC, `searchBar` should start with an upper case S. I think react differentiates native DOM elements and components this way.

Answer (score 1):

Components have to start with Capital letters. So your `class searchBar extends React.Component {` has to become `class SearchBar extends React.Component {` and you have to render it like so:

```
<SearchBar />
```

Comment: good to know, thanks!